# DJango REST Framework - how to pass parameter to serializer __init__

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been reading the django rest framework doc and I couldn't find how to pass parameter to the **init** method of a serializer. In a regular view I do like this:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form_kwargs = super(ContentCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
    form_kwargs['delivery_id'] = self.kwargs['delivery_id']
    return form_kwargs
```

Would you know how I can do that using a CreateAPIView/UpdateAPIView?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't have any references to hand but IIRC this isn't really possible, I think maybe you want to pass stuff through to the serializer context – I find myself pulling the request out of the context in serializers a lot, and generally it's a bit clunky and they're aware of it being less than ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DRF has solutions around this.

Either you need delivery_id to save your instance, in which case you'll pass it directly to [the serializer's save](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save) and get it in the `create`/`update`'s `validated_data`

Either you need it for validation in which case you'll pass it to the [serializer's context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) which you'll be able to use in the serializer/fields as `self.context['request']` for example. You'll need to override the view's `get_serializer_context` for that.